# Visual Studio 2015 Application properties window null reference error

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I click on the properties of a solution the visual studio writes me:

```
An error occurred trying to load the page.
Property accessor 'TargetDescriptions' on object 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectFlavoring.Automation.Project.CommonProjectExtender' threw the following exception:'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: targets'
```

I don't get what does it means. A few day ago it worked and I didn't modified anything that could do this error.

I installed only nuget package manager and Codemaid, but I use them long time ago.

null reference error screenshot:

[image]

What can make problems like this in visual studio 2015 update 2? 
Should I downgrade?

Comment: report it to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the same problem, within a large number of other problems in Visual Studio after the upgrade to Update 2. First of all, I think it's not possible to downgrade. I installed a full Update 1 package trying this but for several parts, like the SDK and Tools for Universal Apps, it would only install these together with Update 2. A bad thing.

But accidentally I solved this error by (re)installing NuGet (https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget) or https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d and then Tools, NuGet Package Manager, Package Manager Console. In this console (where it says PM>) type:
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 
After I installed this package (it shows in References, Micrsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform) , the above error was gone.